# What are '*' , '~' and '%' in makefile?

Tags: makefile

I am learning makefile from GNU documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

It has not defined what *, ~ and % symbols do, for example in the following code snippet:

```
all: hello.so man.so    

%.so: %.o
            $(CXX) -dylib -shared $^ -o $@

.PHONY = clean
clean:
         rm -f *.o *~ *.so
```

Comment: The `*` and `~` don't have anything to do with it being a makefile.  `*.o` is just a shell glob matching all file names that end in `.o`, `*~` is a glob matching all file names ending in `~`, and `*.so` all files ending in `.so`. If you look closer, you'll find that the document you linked does discuss `%`.

Comment: Maybe I skipped that section (there's too much, I'm only reading the start of most chapters). Could you point me to which chapter/ subchapter in the link where % is defined?

Comment: Just open the site and do a search for `%.` By the way, one common name convention in Linux for a temporary file is to end it in `~` which is why the `clean` target removes files ending in `~`.